# Nexus 5x stuck in download mode after flashing

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5

I flashed my nexus 5x following the instructions from the official android website https://developers.google.com/android/images . I installed `fastboot` on my `Ubuntu 16.04` and started flashing. After executing the script `flash-all.sh`, it indicates that the phone was properly flashed in terminal, and even my phone shows commands that the firmware is getting installed. But after the end of the flash, my phone reboot and get stuck on a the message :

```
Firmware Update
Do not unplug the USB connection until the process is complete
```

with a progress bar stuck at 0%.

I've tried flashing with the firmwares : 6.0.0 (MDA89E), 7.0.0 (NRD90M), 7.1.1 (NMF26F, Dec 2016). And with every firmware I get stuck after the flashing ends.

## Note

When I visited a link given by sancho.s , I noticed that I can't get into `recovery mode`, my phone get stuck into the same `Firmware Update` screen unstead.

Comment: You might edit your question with a detailed list of the alternatives you tried (description step-by-step), and what you get. An image may also be useful. That will help others help you. Did you remove the battery?

Answer (score 1):

There was no specific question posted, so I asume you have your phone bricked (unusable) now, and you want to get it out of that state.
Here you find a few alternatives:

1. Two people reported [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-lg-g2/392033-firmware-update-has-my-lgg2-frozen.html) that unplugging the cable, then holding the power button down restarts the phone, and it likely brings it back to life. Similarly [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2531032)... And there are plenty of similar posts around.
   *You commented that this does not work*.
2. There are further instructions [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/w6lEbpTOCwA).
3. From [here](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-fix-a-frozen-nexus): 
   "If a battery pull doesn't fix the problem, turn your phone off, charge the battery sufficiently (while it's off) and then unplug from the charger. Hold Volume Down and Power to enter HBoot and enter recovery. Once you see the error symbol pull the battery out again and then reinsert the battery and start as normal. This (for some reason) works for a lot of people. If all else fails enter recovery and do a factory reset."

Comment: I've already tried that, but nothing happens. It is always stuck in the `Firmware Update` screen.

Comment: @Sidahmed - Please see updated answer. You might edit your question with a detailed list of the alternatives you tried (description step-by-step). That will help others help you. Did you remove the battery?

Comment: I just edited my question, that's basically all what I did. I will try to pull out the battery, but I will need sometime for that to get the appropriate material.

Comment: I'm trying to open the phone, but I can't even move the screw, is it normal ??

Comment: I think that I won't resolve this question before the end of the bounty, but thank you for your help. The bounty will be given to you.

Comment: @Sidahmed - I never tried opening a Nexus 5x, so I wouldn't know about the screw. But a couple of videos may help, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3WImb3povQ , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOOfoX78mpA . And also https://www.google.com/search?q=remove+nexus+5x+battery&tbm=vid